# Remove Specific Top Links

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, toplinks

I need to edit the Magento Top Links in a specific way and only need to show three links in below order

```
Login  Register  Cart
```

This would result in following

1. **Remove only Checkout Link and not Cart Link**
2. **Remove My account Link and add Register Link instead**
3. **Rename My Cart to Cart**

How can I achieve this ?

Please Guide.

Thanks !!!

Comment: How can I do it using top.links.phtml ?

Answer (score 11):

You can also remove some of the top links in your local.xml by referencing them and removing them by name.

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
   <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
</reference>
```

This only work if the top link was created with a name like this:

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
   <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

For the log in and log out, since they aren't called with a "name", you can't remove it this way.

Answer (score 6):

you can modify it by edit **reference name="top.links"** block in following **.xml** files

```
 1. app/design/frontend/Your_theme/default/layout/checkout.xml 
 2. app/design/frontend/Your_theme/default/layout/customer.xml
```

Check this following  post

[How to edit header links?](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-edit-header-links.html)

You can get more idea from here

Comment: yeah. Its my answer! Its only suggestion for you!

Comment: Mark, this is not constructive. What did you do? What is the problem? What did you expect to happen. And please edit the question to add more information and DON'T write a unreadable comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
   <!-- Removes 'Log Out' link-->

   <reference name="top.links">
      <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
         <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
      </action>
   </reference>
```

Reference: http://sarathlal.com/remove-top-links-in-magento/